# Возможно ли использовать dll написанную на C# в проекте на C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Знаю что обратное возможно, а как быть с dll С# --> C++?

Comment: Сделать её COMVisible - самый простой вариант

Comment: Обратное вроде как невозможно. Заметьте, что возможность вызвать С код - это не то же самое. Ну а вообще еще есть страшный C++/CLI

Comment: Если оборачивать в COM, то всё равно будет нужна платформа .NET?

Answer (score -1):

Возможно и вообще нет разницы, на чём dll написана, так как dll это законченный exe файл, но с несколькими точками входа/запуска. Вы любую dll можете вообще автономно запустить программой rundll32.

Теперь COM, в его основе лежит механизм RPC (DCE/RPC), то есть разделение клиента и сервера по сети, теоретически это с .NET вообще никак не связано, а практически зависит от вашего случая.